# Sequelize search is not working as expected

Tags: sequelize.js

I am new to Sequelize and trying to run some filters(search) against some fields.

here is my data:

```
{
"is_archived": false,
"details": {
    "query_str": "this is my test and only test",
    "expiry_time": 1689966137000
},
"status": "COMPLETED",
"creation_time": "1689793338350",

"last_accessed_on": "1689793338351"
```

}
in a jsonb filed in Postgres
When I run this where clause I get the result I want (the above rows returns)

```
      where: {
    "details.query_str":  { [Op.iLike]: "%my test%" },

  }
```

but when I run

```
      where: {
     "details.expiry_time":  { [Op.gt]: 2689966137000 }

  }
```

I do not get what I want (nothing should return but all the rows in db instead returns)

Update: when I look at the generate sequelize command in where clause I do not even see anything related to details.expiry_time

Comment: Can you provide the code that you use for this searches?